# Does IIS Application Pool switch worker thread?

Tags: c#, iis, log4net

I have a web service hosting on a IIS 8 Application Pool. I am using log4net to log.

I was inspecting some entries in a log file and notice the thread id got change.

Here are the two log entries

```
<event logger="ManageStaticData" 
       timestamp="2015-08-14T03:00:00.0597938-06:00" 
       level="INFO" 
       thread="5916" 
       domain="Webservice" 
       username="IIS APPPOOL\WebServices">
  <message>Start of static data load.</message>
  <global-properties>
    <data name="log4net:HostName" value="CC" />
  </global-properties>
</event>
<event logger="ManageStaticData" 
       timestamp="2015-08-14T03:00:00.3410242-06:00" 
       level="DEBUG" 
       thread="eba102cb-8224-426e-a2b1-f4e984d4dea7" 
       domain="Webservice" 
       username="IIS APPPOOL\WebServices">
  <message>Found 1 schedule to be load</message>
  <global-properties>
    <data name="log4net:HostName" value="CC" />
  </global-properties>
</event>
```

The code path that shows these two log message can only come from the same method.

Notice the thread value changed from "5916" to a GUID.

After about 6 seconds, I notice that the 5916 thread start logging other web service calls. The thread with the GUID is no longer logging.

Why does the thread value change? Did log4net use a worker thread to log the entries? Or did IIS somehow switch the worker thread in the middle of the process, sound unlikely? Or is it the same thread, but got renamed?

Answer (score 1):

Each request is assigned to an available thread as it comes in. The thread id changed because you the log entries represent two separate web requests.

Comment: I am pretty sure they come from the same web request. I did it under a test environment and I only invoke the web service call once. The web service method also has a Monitor.TryEnter preventing multiple web request calls running the same code at the same time. In addition, the code that generate these comments are very close to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Each request gets its own worker thread.

Each `await` of `async` method have chance to switching threads too during single request.

Early/late steps of ASP.Net pipeline may be swithcing threads too for singe request even if your code (which is usually the middle of pipeline steps) does not use async/await.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this Early/late steps of ASP.NET that can switch thread without using async? I am trying to look up more information about thread switching in ASP.NET , but so far they only mention it only happens if I use asynchronous handlers, or async/await. In the code, it uses Monitor.TryEnter, and using Entity Framework to load data.

Comment: I think I found a possibility of the thread being switched. The code in between the logs actually made a web service call (another web service). I need to test it more, but it is very likely the another web service come back on a different thread.